# scrapy returns null output

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy spider is returning empty list [] for below, although my xpath is correct. Can anyone pls let me know, what am I doing wrong

```
class QuotesScraper(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=ceo+or+founder+united+states+recruitment++email+%22gmail.com%22+site:linkedin.com&sxsrf=ALeKk02ihJu-y-i_M78VfGxVc4hTZGfzNw:1628243384010&ei=uAUNYcUI2pL1A7amgfAB&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjFxIukj5zyAhVaSX0KHTZTAB44eBDy0wN6BAgBEDo&biw=1366&bih=625"]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h3[@class="LC20lb DKV0Md"]').extract()
        yield{'title_text':title}


 scrapy crawl quotes

output:

{'title_text': []}
```

Comment: your ```start_urls``` looks wrong. Copy and paste it in a browser and see where it takes you to. Google, right?

Comment: yes am trying to scrape from search results. url is correct. Noticed weird thing. In page source h3 tag, class has value "LC20lb DKV0Md". However when scrapy returns the html  for same h3 tag class has value "zBAuLc". seems strange. Now with this value I am able to fetch elements but still facing issues extracting text from same.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is wrong.

1. Scrapy doesn't support javascript. Before you check the html response, disable javascript of your browser.
2. The class value seems to be dynamically generated. Try another xpath selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
for title in response.xpath('//h3[@class="LC20lb DKV0Md"]'):
    yield {'title': title.xpath('::text').get()}
```